# Using AJAX to generate behind the scenes?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to create images using `imagejpeg()` but they seem to take longer to render than the time it takes to load the page, therefore the images are either not displaying or they are truncated.

I have tried to delay the loading of the page until the images are completely created without resolve so now I am attempting to get the images created prior to page load.

My fail is as follows:

```
function createimages(x) {
    $.post("image-dev.php?curID=" + x, function(rdata) {
        console.log(rdata);
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
        window.location = "image-review.php?curID=" + x;
    }, 5000);
}
```

image-dev.php is my image creation file that pulls all necessary data from my DB then uses imagejpeg to create and save my folder.

If I navigate directly to image-dev.php with the proper ID associated. My images are created and saved properly.

My hopes were that I could use AJAX to call image-dev.php sometime before loading the image review page. I hoped that this would 'pre-develop' the images so that they would load properly when reviewed.

My console.log of the rdata shows that the image-dev.php is loading and executing, but the files aren't being created.

Is there an issue with creating images behind the scene?

Comment: what's the big picture, what are the images? what's the data used to create them?

Comment: If your script creates images and _saves_ them to the file system afterwards, then this can only be a one-time issue I suppose, when that particular image is requested for the first time – and after that the file system serves as “cache”, and the image can be served from there directly circumventing the dynamic creation? So why would there any need to complicate this with AJAX then …?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When image is already created php can return "true".
With ajax you can do that.

```
function createimages(x){
  $.ajax({
    url: "image-dev.php?curID="+x,
    beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
    //here you can hide elements or other DOM manipulations
  }
  }).done(function( rdata) {
    console.log(rdata);
   //when php is ready you can show images or other DOM manipulations
  }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

kristiyan, Thanks!

I have decided to give up on the idea of predeveloping my images and used your tactic.

Since the images were still truncating when displayed, I now have placeholder images on the image review page and am loading the new images in after they complete.

I'm not yet sure how to see if an image is truncated, so I had to add in a delay before resetting the placeholders src attribute.

```
$.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: "image-dev.php?curID="+x,

     success: function(rdata) {
       console.log(rdata);
       setTimeout(function(){
           $('#placeholder').attr('src', 'newImage.jpg'); 
       },5000);  
     }
});
```

This seems to be working acceptably!